# Criar uma matriz/Arrays com base em um arquivo TXT

Tags: array, matriz, fortran

Sou nova no uso da linguagem Fortran/95 e quero extrair alguns dados de um arquivo txt (http://1drv.ms/20gSNKb), são dados de vazão disponíveis no portal HidroWeb. Considerando que eles sejam separados por ";" , como o exemplo:

```
//EstacaoCodigo;NivelConsistencia;Data;Hora;MediaDiaria;MetodoObtencaoVazoes;Maxima;Minima;Media;DiaMaxima;DiaMinima;MaximaStatus;MinimaStatus;MediaStatus
88850000;2;08/01/1964;;1;1;;;;;;0;0;0
88850000;2;09/01/1964;;1;1;50.24;2.78;6.446;30;14;1;1;1
88850000;2;10/01/1964;;1;1;364.4;3.26;1.744.774;9;31;1;1;1
88850000;2;11/01/1964;;1;1;7.6;1.18;2.224;21;27;1;1;1
88850000;2;12/01/1964;;1;1;3.1;0.575;1.118.226;2;21;1;1;1
88850000;2;01/01/1965;;1;1;16.2;0.315;1.214.194;17;14;1;1;1
88850000;2;02/01/1965;;1;1;6.6;0.1762;0.6019143;3;21;1;1;1
88850000;2;03/01/1965;;1;1;63;0.127;6.706.581;28;10;1;1;1
```

Preciso dar entrada destes dados e retira as informações referentes as colunas Est - Data - Máxima - Média - Mínima e gerar um novo txt.

A rotina que construí esta descrita abaixo

```
 PROGRAM dadospluv
 IMPLICIT NONE
 integer :: i
 OPEN(UNIT=10, FILE="vazoes_bruna.txt", STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ')
 READ(10,*) n, (a(i), i=1,n)
```

Estou com duvida de como posso criar a matriz/arrays para manipular os dados. Alguma dica?

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOPT @bruna, poderia [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer, colocar algum trecho de código que você já tentou realizar, como são os dados nesse arquivo de texto, poderia postar? De que forma a disposição dos texto do arquivo deve ficar organizada na matriz? Obrigado.

Comment: @bruna eu respondi à sua outra questão em [Ler arquivos com “;” no fortran](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109606/ler-arquivos-com-no-fortran/109936). Por favor, verifique se ajudou a solucionar o dúvida  para ler os dados.