# Ler arquivos com ";" no fortran

Tags: fortran

Preciso ler uma matriz onde os dados estão **separados/delimitados** por **`;`**, mas fica dando erro.

Esse é o layout do arquivo para leitura dos dados:

```fortran
//EstacaoCodigo;NivelConsistencia;Data;Hora;MediaDiaria;MetodoObtencaoVazoes;Maxima;Minima;Media;DiaMaxima;DiaMinima;MaximaStatus;MinimaStatus;MediaStatus
88850000;2;08/01/1964;;1;1;;;;;;0;0;0
88850000;2;09/01/1964;;1;1;50.24;2.78;6.446;30;14;1;1;1
88850000;2;10/01/1964;;1;1;364.4;3.26;1.744.774;9;31;1;1;1
88850000;2;11/01/1964;;1;1;7.6;1.18;2.224;21;27;1;1;1
88850000;2;12/01/1964;;1;1;3.1;0.575;1.118.226;2;21;1;1;1
88850000;2;01/01/1965;;1;1;16.2;0.315;1.214.194;17;14;1;1;1
88850000;2;02/01/1965;;1;1;6.6;0.1762;0.6019143;3;21;1;1;1
88850000;2;03/01/1965;;1;1;63;0.127;6.706.581;28;10;1;1;1
```

> O código que eu fiz foi esse:

```fortran
program vazoes
implicit none

INTEGER, DIMENSION(3,80) :: a
INTEGER :: row,col,max_rows,max_cols
max_rows=3
max_cols=80

open(Unit = 11, file = 'vazoes.txt', status = 'old')
DO row = 1,max_rows
    READ(11,*) (a(row,col),col=1,max_cols)
END DO

PRINT *, a(1,:)
END PROGRAM vazoes
```

Como ler esses dados usando **[fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran)**?

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias estratégias possíveis para efetuar a leitura do arquivo no formato csv com delimitador `';'` e separar os campos lidos.

Abaixo segue um exemplo comentado, que efetua a leitura de cada linha do arquivo e a armazena na variável `linha_texto`.

O looping que está logo após a leitura da linha, percorre cada caracter da linha e procura por um `';'` e, caso encontre, armazena o "último" valor em um item do array `dados`.

Após esse looping, todas as (78) colunas encontram-se disponíveis no array e são impressas separadamente na saída padrão (console).

```
PROGRAM vazoes

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: i

    ! A variavel status verifica se houve 
    ! algum erro ao abrir o arquivo
    INTEGER :: status = 0

    ! Contador de posições de campos e número de campos
    INTEGER :: posicao_campo = 0, campos = 0

    ! Aloca espaco para leitura de uma linha de texto
    CHARACTER*2048 :: linha_texto

    ! Aloca espaço para um registro do banco de dados (78 campos)
    CHARACTER*32, DIMENSION(78) :: dados

    ! Abre o arquivo
    OPEN(UNIT=15, IOSTAT=status, FILE='vazoes.txt', STATUS='OLD')

    ! Verifica se houve erro ao abrir o arquivo
    IF (status .GT. 0) THEN
        WRITE(*,*) "Erro ao abrir o arquivo!"
        ! Finaliza a execução se houve erro
        STOP
    ENDIF

    ! Looping de leitura do arquivo
    DO
        ! Lê uma linha completa (um registro)
        READ(15, '(A)', IOSTAT=status) linha_texto

        ! Verifica se chegou no final do arquivo...
        IF (status .LT. 0) THEN
            ! ...e sai do looping se finalizou
            EXIT
        ENDIF

        ! Separa os campos utilizando o ';' como delimitador
        posicao_campo = 1
        campos = 1

        DO i=1,LEN(linha_texto)
            ! se encontrar o ';'...
            IF (linha_texto(i:i) == ';') THEN                
                ! ...adiciona o campo no array 'dados'
                dados(campos) = linha_texto(posicao_campo:i-1)
                campos = campos + 1
                ! marca a posição do último ';' encontrado
                posicao_campo = i+1
            ENDIF            
        ENDDO

        ! Imprime cada campo em formato texto na saída padrão
        WRITE(*,*) 'Inicio'
        DO i=1,campos-1            
            WRITE(*,*) dados(i)
        ENDDO
        WRITE(*,*) 'Fim.'

    END DO

    ! Fecha o arquivo    
    CLOSE(UNIT=15, IOSTAT=status)    
    ! Verifica se houve erro ao fechar o arquivo    
    IF (status .GT. 0) THEN
        WRITE(*,*) "Erro ao fechar o arquivo!"
        ! Finaliza a execução se houve erro
        STOP
    ENDIF

END PROGRAM vazoes
```

A organização dos registros lidos na variável `dados` e a conversão dos dados para os tipos corretos (data, inteiro, etc.) precisa ser implementada e depende do objetivo de processamento que você pretende implementar no programa.

Caso o formato do arquivo de dados mude, é necessário alterar o programa ou implementar uma estratégia de alocação dinâmica (ex: *ALLOCATE*) dos arrays, que se adapte a formatos variáveis durante o tempo de execução (*'runtime'*).